# List all gc-roots that reference Nix package

Tags: nix

I'm trying to remove package X entirely from my `/nix/store/`, but `nix-garbage-collect` wont remove it as its probably referenced by some garbage collection root (gc-root) somewhere. Is it possible to list which gc-roots reference a given package X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program [nix-du](https://github.com/symphorien/nix-du) can provide you with a graph showing which gc-roots reference which packages, but it also does the additional work of calculating the size of each package.